# javascript custom console log function keeping stack trace

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a helper function that prepends some message when calling `console.log`:

```js
function log(...arg: any[]): void {
  const LOG_PREFIX = `[file.ts]`;
  // 1. Convert args to a normal array
  const args: any[] = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  // 2. Prepend log prefix log string
  args.unshift(LOG_PREFIX);
  // 3. Pass along arguments to console.log
  console.log.call(console, ...args);
}
```

The problem is that when it logs, the console shows a clickable link to this `log:8` or the line that calls `console.log.call(console, ...args)`

Is there a way I can adjust this method so that it keeps the intended stack trace of where i call this method instead?

Comment: This looks like `typescript` not `javascript`...I think it's not possible change stack trace. also since you have an array of arguments, its probably better use `apply()` instead of `call()`, in which case you can achieve the same thing with one-liner: `console.log.apply(console, ["[file.ts]", ...arg]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go, [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is to the rescue:

```js
const log = console.log.bind(window.console, "[file.ts]");

log("test", "blah");
console.log("test", "blah");
```